# PowerShell - foreach loop every 1 minute

Tags: powershell

I have a script that queries AD and if it finds users created within 24 hours it will email them. I have this part working fine, but I can't seem to figure out why 1) it works line by line in PowerShell windows but not running the exact same code as a .ps1 file; and 2) why the $name field in the $mailBody is not displaying at all. It is displaying $username but not $name. I'll post the error message below the code.

```
clear
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("xxx@xxx.com", $secpasswd)
$PSEmailServer = "xxx@xxx.com"
$SMTPPort = 587
$SMTPUsername = "xxx@xxx.com"
$MailFrom = "xxx@xxx.com"
$MailSubject = "Your user account has been created"

#Pull users created within last 24 hours

$when =  ((get-date).AddDays(-2)).addMinutes(-0) #past 24 hours from current time
$when
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $when} -Properties whenCreated,mail,givenname,surname,SAMAccountName,info | Select-Object whenCreated,mail,givenname,surname,SAMAccountName,info | where info -ne true

Foreach ($user in $users) 
{
$users
$name = $user.name
$emailTo = $user.mail
$username = $user.SAMAccountName
$MailBody =" <p>Dear $name,
Your CDAT Account has been created. <br><br>
Your Username is $username <br><br>
Please contact CDAT support for further assistance. <br><br>
CDAT Support Team <br><br>

This email was auto-generated. Please do not reply. If you need assistance, please contact CDAT Support. <br><br>
Confidentiality Notice: This email message, including any attachments, is for the sole use of the intended recipient(s), and may contain confidential and privileged information. Any unauthorized review, use, disclosure, or distribution is prohibited. If you are not the intended recipient, please contact the sender by reply email and destroy all copies of the original message.<br><br>
</P>"
    Send-MailMessage -From $MailFrom -To $emailTo -Subject $MailSubject -Body $MailBody -BodyAsHtml -Port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $mycreds
    Set-AdUser -identity $username –replace @{info=”true”}


}

"PS C:\scripts> .\EmailUsers24HoursAfterAccountCreation.ps1
At C:\scripts\EmailUsers24HoursAfterAccountCreation.ps1:33 char:36
+         Set-AdUser -identity $username â€“replace @{info=â€trueâ€}
+                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\scripts\EmailUsers24HoursAfterAccountCreation.ps1:18 char:2
+     {
+     ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString"
```

Comment: In a powershell prmpt, type: `Get-Help Start-Sleep -Detailed`

Comment: I'd just use a scheduled task, you can deal with failure and long running tasks gracefully that way. If you've got it setup correctly it will continue working after a reboot too.

Comment: The problem is once a user is queried in the script they're emailed if it was created within 24 hours. So, if we run the task every 1 hour, it's going to email that same user 24 times throughout that 24 hour period. Due to security, we cannot store a file with the users (which would make it easier to exclude them), so I have to use a running array. I think I can make an attribute in one of the many AD fields that correlates to a "true" flag. So say once a user is emailed, it adds a "true" to that attribute, and then my AD query will filter out users with that flag.

Comment: Personally I would just have it dump the list of user IDs that are in AD at the end of it running. Then the next time it runs it only cares about users that are not in that list.

Comment: @EBGreen do you mean dump into a file? One major requirement is that I cannot export anything, it has to be a running array. I kind of have this working but it's not looping properly. My loop gets users created within 24 hours "where info -ne true" (that's my custom flag I added so that it excludes users and does not keep emailing them. Then my loop says foreach $user in $users send-mailmessage and also set-aduser to set the info flag to true. Problem is, it only seems to take the last entry in $users. If I echo the users, it DOES pull all the users but only does the action for the last user

Comment: Well, it sounds like you have made substantive changes to your code. You should probably edit your question to show the code that you are now running and explain how specifically that code does not meet your needs.

Comment: @EBGreen edited. So even after the last comment, I made slightly more changes (posted above) which now, it seems it's looping properly, sending the mail to all users created after "x" time, editing that user and adding a true flag to the "@info" field, and then my query excludes users with the "true" flag. However, when it sends my mail, my body is only showing the last "@name" or "@username" from the foreach loop. It's not displaying the true identity.

Comment: you are creating your email body outside of the loop that goes through each account. So $username would not be changing in the email body.

Comment: @EBGreen okay we're getting there! Two things not working properly now. 1) the $name field is blank on the emails. I've tried moving the $name = $user.name outside and inside the foreach, same result.The $username field displays just fine which is strange. Also, when I run the script manually line by line, it executes just fine, but when I run it as a .ps1 file it errors out stating Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition. The block is definitely closed off and it clearly works if I do this all manually line by line....

Comment: Please edit your code to what you are actually running right now.

Comment: @EBGreen edited. So again, line by line works but it still has the $name not displaying properly. And if I run this exact code as a .ps1 it returns this "At c:\scripts\EmailUsers24HoursAfterAccountCreation.ps1:33 char:36
+ Set-AdUser -identity $username â€“replace @{info=â€trueâ€}
+The string is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\scripts\EmailUsers24HoursAfterAccountCreation.ps1:18 char:2
+ {
+     ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString"

Comment: Ugh...please always edit your question to show errors. Reading them in comments sucks. Having siad that you are having file encoding issue.

Comment: @EBGreen sorry about that. This is all new to me. I've edited with the error messages.

Comment: @EBGreen okay I got the script running. Like you said, must have been an encoding issue I couldn't see. I copied my code from N++ into a regular notepad file and saved that as .ps1, and that worked. However, still having the $name issue where it's not displaying at all. Thoughts?

Comment: I got it working! I wasn't defining $name properly. My filter was pulling "givenname" and not "user.name" which is what I had $name =. So I changed to $name = user.givenname and it's now working. I think all is working right now.